# CodeBehind could not load type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this strange problem with my code. When it runs on my local machine it works great, but when I publish it on the server, it suddenly can not retrieve type. It seems that it does not export all files.  The Error I receive
[image: Error Received]

I tried CodeFile and it works but I receive same error later on where it can not load ObjectDataSource. I checked inheritance and it seems OK....

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TheDatabase.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_VehicleList" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>V4</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" DataSourceID="ods_PnDetails">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Vehicle" HeaderText="Vehicle" SortExpression="Vehicle" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VCC" HeaderText="VCC" SortExpression="VCC" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantM1" HeaderText="QuantM1" SortExpression="QuantM1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="VehM1" HeaderText="VehM1" SortExpression="VehM1" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="JCI" HeaderText="JCI" SortExpression="JCI" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods_PnDetails" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetResult" TypeName="TheDatabase.PNDetailsDataAccessLayer">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddl_VehicleList" DefaultValue="V4" Name="VehicleID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

THen it comes Default.aspx.cs which is empty

```
using System;

namespace TheDatabase
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }

}
```

and my object data source

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TheDatabase
{
    public class SQLUlaznaTabela
    {
        public string Vehicle { get; set; }
        public string VCC { get; set; }
        public string QuantM1 { get; set; }
        public string VehM1 { get; set; }
        public string JCI { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class PNDetailsDataAccessLayer
    {
        public PNDetailsDataAccessLayer()
        {

        }
        public List<SQLUlaznaTabela> GetResult(string VehicleID)
        {
            List<SQLUlaznaTabela> ulaz = new List<SQLUlaznaTabela>();
            string SC = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QuotationCalculationDB"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(SC))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Vehicle, VCC,QuantM1,VehM1,Description from ProdPerVehicleLastYear where Vehicle = @Vehicle", con);
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Vehicle", VehicleID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    SQLUlaznaTabela ulazniRed = new SQLUlaznaTabela();
                    ulazniRed.Vehicle = rdr["Vehicle"].ToString();
                    ulazniRed.VCC = rdr["VCC"].ToString();
                    ulazniRed.QuantM1 = rdr["QuantM1"].ToString();
                    ulazniRed.VehM1 = rdr["VehM1"].ToString();
                    ulazniRed.Description = rdr["Description"].ToString();
                    ulaz.Add(ulazniRed);
                }

            }

            return ulaz;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you publishing the site?

Comment: Build=>Publish TheDatabase=>FileSytem and target location is folder on server

Comment: Try changing `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` as this: `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TheDatabase.Default" %>`. If you have access to IIS in server, right click the site and use "Convert to Application" then ensure all compiled DLLs already updated.

Comment: Well, solution was more then simple, and you gave me idea... You need to start your application in IIS if you plan to use it.. CodeBehind works as well. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quite confused because my code was OK and it turned out that I have not started my application in IIS. Shame on me...